# How to read and write binary SHA1 digest from std::fstream

Tags: c++, character-encoding, file-handling

I need to read and write a hex encoded SHA1 value in the file.
If I wanted to write `C30A` then I need to convert `C30A` into character array whose length is equal to half the length of the hashvalue since a byte can hold two hex characters;
for `C30A`,

```cpp
    char array[2];
    array[0] = 11000011=195;
    array[1] = 00001010=10;//which is an ascii for '\n'
```

If I wanted to write this `char array`
I have done: `filestream<<array;`

Now when I want to read it from file how should I read it?

I tried doing

```cpp
    std::string str;
    filestream>>str;
```

But it stops whenever it encounters whitespace characters like `'\0'`,`'\r'`,`'\n'` etc.
And It always ends up reading only a portion of the hash, since there will be those character for sure.

What way should I go to read and write in this case?

Comment: Doesn't get line stops on encountering '\n'?

Comment: Please get your terminology straight. "hex encoding" typically means that you represent binary data as hex digits. You are writing and reading a binary file.

Comment: f you want to read and write raw binary data, first of all use binary files (open with the `std::ios_base::binary` flag), then read and write raw data with `read` or `write`. Don't mix in text- or character-based functions and operators.

Answer (score 1):

If there is nothing else in the file, know that a SHA1 digest is 160 bits, or 20 bytes:

```
string sha1(20, '\0');
filestream.read(sha1.data(), sha1.size());
```